# FTP Logs in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I know this is weird, but the thruth is that I can't find the FTP logs in one IIS 7.5 Server.

In the IIS Management Console, I've gone to the server, click on FTP Logging that appears inside FTP group (with other options like FTP Messages and FTP Request filtering). Seems that the configured folder for logs is:

- C:\InetPubFolder\logs\LogFiles

If I go there, I can find a lot of folders with the structure W3SVC#, where # it's a number. They all contain logs, but they are HTTP logs, plenty of GET and POST verbs.

Am I missing something?

The server contains a lot of domains and It's hard to find.

**UPDATE:**

**Don't Know if this helps, but the IIS is working with Plesk. It's curious, but I can't find FTP sites as I did with IIS6. If I do a telnet to 21 port appears:**

**220 Microsoft FTP Service**

Answer (score 0):

try sending a file to the ftp server.  It may not have 'initialized' and created the logging directory.  Also, make sure that logging is turned 'on' - it might be configured, but not enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot James!. Sorry, it doesn't make a difference. In theory, a lot of webs are making use of the FTP right now.